# I have a shortcode for a WP Currency Converter that is in style.css stylesheet but not visible on my website

Tags: css

I have searched in the questions but cannot find an answer to my problem.
I am new to css code. I have taken over my website maintenance from my website designer. I have a WP Currency Converter plugin activated. My ex-designer used the shortcode in my Child Theme stylesheet style.css, shortcode-wpcc-widget-. The currency converter appeared in each of my product pages of my WooCommerce Shop up until last week, but now has disappeared. Please advise how I can fix this. This is all the code related to the wpcc in the sytle.css sheet.

```
div#shortcode-wpcc-widget- {

    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
input#wpcc_convert {

    background-color: #e44049;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input#wpcc_convert:hover {

    background-color: #e62732;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div#shortcode-wpcc-widget- h3 {

    color: #e44049;
}
select#wpcc_currency_from {

    padding: 5px;
}
select#wpcc_currency_to {

    padding: 5px;
}
input#wpcc_currency_amount {

    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You can't use shortcodes in CSS. Has the shortcode been removed from the page content from within the WordPress admin panel?

Comment: I don't think it is about adding shortcodes in css @DanielJames, this is just the style added to the widget... I think the problem is that the widget does not appear anymore on his pages. So this is not the right code to provide for this question... I would check if the plugin for some strange reason got uninstalled. Or check if the widget is still active under "Apperance" -> "Widgets"

Comment: Thanks to you both for your answers from someone who is brand new to all of this. I will go back to the drawing board as plugin is active and is active under appearance in widgets.

Comment: Why not inspect the page where the converter used to be and see if any CSS is hiding it? It seems like you're assuming that's the cause, but none of the code you've posted looks suspect.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into it.